# Como ocultar y evitar que aparezca de nuevo el navigationBar en una Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity

Estoy intentando evitar que se muestre el `navigationBar` en el `Activity` de una `App`, el fin es evitar que el usuario tenga acceso al `navigationBar` para no poder salir de esa `App` o `Activity` a menos que realice un `logout` en dicha actividad. Investigando en la documentación oficial de `Android`, vi la opción de hacer un `FullScreen` en dicha `Activity`, el problema esta que con los gestos en los bordes o al presionar los botones de volumen, muestra el `navigationBar` por al menos unos segundos, y esto también quiero evitarlo, existe la posibilidad de hacer eso?

En este código intento hacer eso:

```
    private int currentApiVersion;

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus)
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

NOTA: También uso un `fragment` en esta `Activity`, por si la manera de hacerlo involucra `fragments`. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ocultar la barra de navegación (NavigationBar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma de realizarlo, puedes configurar su visibilidad desde el método `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Esconde NavigationBar
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa :

[Esconder la NavigationBar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)

Comment: si ese método entiendo como funciona, el problema es que así al tocar la pantalla me muestra el `navigationBar` de nuevo y se mantiene, el código que coloque hace que se oculte al cabo de unos segundos, lo que quiero hacer es que sin importar los toques, gestos y botones de subir y bajar volumen, la `navigationBar` se mantenga oculta siempre, y solo se muestre en otra actividad luego que el usuario haga un `Logout`.